# JSON column formatting with if/else in SharePoint?

Tags: json-formatting

I would like to nest if conditions into SharePoint via JSON column format.

I have two fields, Date and Status.
The status field contains 3 strings ("Done", "Pending", "New")

Example:

```
if ([$Date] < @NOW) {
    if([$Status] == "Done") {
        font color GREEN
    } else {
        font color RED
    }
} elseif ([$Date] == @NOW) {
    if([$Status] == "Job done") {
        font color GREEN
    } else {
        font color RED
    }
} else {
    font color black;
}
```

And my Json code so far... (Only the first condition)

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$DeadLine] <= @now + 86400000, '#FAFAFA', '#22ff00')"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note I haven't tested this code, but the concept is how to solve this.  You will have to nest the IF statements.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$DeadLine] < @now, " +
        "if([$Status] <= 'Done', '#00FF00', '#FF0000')," + /* TRUE CONDITION, DeadLine < Now */
        "if([$DeadLine] == @now, " + /* False Condition Deadline is NOT less than Now: Second if statement */
            "if([$Status] == 'Job done', '#00FF00' , '#FF0000' )," + /* Values for Status = Job done */
        "'#000000'))" /* when all else fails, black */
  }
}
```

Same code as a single line without comments

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$DeadLine] < @now, if([$Status] <= 'Done', '#00FF00', '#FF0000'), if([$DeadLine] == @now, if([$Status] == 'Job done', '#00FF00' , '#FF0000' ),'#000000'))"
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems reasonable for your 3 choices. What if you wanted different formatting for each of 5 or 20 cases. Does it allow switch or case syntax?